# Rails Generate Devise:Controllers not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Simple question.

I'm using **Rails 4.1.4** and **Devise 3.3.0** for my app.

I'm trying to generate **Devise**'s controllers so I can override some behaviour.

Documentation says to run...

> rails generate devise:controllers [scope]

... to generate controllers under *app/controllers/scope* so you can then modify them. But when I run the previous command it keeps saying that there is no generator *devise:controllers*:

> Could not find generator devise:controllers.

Does anyone knows why?.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

In fact, when I run...

> rails generate

... to retrieve a list of the available generators, I get the following output for **Devise** generators:

> Devise:
>
> devise
>
> devise:install
>
> devise:views

So definitelly, the **devise:controllers** generator isn't there. Is there a way to add it?. How?.

Thanks.

Comment: it might help ? http://excid3.com/blog/rails-3-could-not-find-generator-deviseinstall/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I've just created the controller manually and make it inherit from **Devise**. For example:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    # Override the action you want here.
end
```

This controller should live in *app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb*. If you have any other *scope* just go with *app/controllers/scope/registrations_controller.rb*. For example if you have an *admin* scope it would be *app/controllers/admins/registrations_controller.rb*.

Best.

**UPDATE**

Following the comment from *blushrt*, I forgot to mention that it is important to modify *config/routes.rb* to make **Devise** use the created controller for the specific resource. For example, for *users*, you should put in your *config/routes.rb*:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }
```

That's it. Best.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the OP's original question of **"Does anyone knows why?"**

The problem is that this generator is currently only available on Devise's master branch, as stated on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3222#issuecomment-56727520).

If you want to use this feature before it's published, you could add this to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'devise', git: 'https://github.com/plataformatec/devise'
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers

You can run this command in your terminal.

```
bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/foohey/cdc/master/cdc.sh)
```

Comment: You can just create a controller manually and have it inherit from devise. For example     class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController      for the registrations controller, if you want to override the session controller have it in from Devise::SessionsController

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here in case anyone else has this (silly) problem. I couldn't work out why a POST to /users kept routing to Devise::RegistrationsController#create rather than Users::RegistrationsController#create

The reason?

I had a typo in routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registations: 'users/registrations }
```

Note I had registations instead of registrations

So be wary you may have a typo in your route somewhere